# Error Declaration Expected

Tags: typescript, angular

I am using typescript version 1.8 and getting this error. I am new to typescript please help.
npm version: 3.9

*File: ponymain-app.component.ts*

```
 import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
        selector: 'ponyracer-app',
        template: `<h1>Hye bud!</h1>`
    })
```

File: Index.html

```
<body>
  <ponyracer-app>
    loading....
  </ponyracer-app>
</body>
```

Comment: Is this your whole `ponymain-app.component.ts` file?

Comment: Any more details about the error message?

Comment: Yes a complete file. I am just starting a project in angular and just got this message in command line. After tsc --watch

Answer (score 4):

You need to attach the @Component decorator to a class directly and you will not get anything until you bootstrap your root component

I am assuming you main root component is PonyComponent

Here's a edited version of your code

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import {Component} from '@angular/core'; 

@Component({ 
selector: 'ponyracer-app', 
template: `<h1>Hye bud!</h1>` 
}) 

class PonyComponent { }

bootstrap( PonyComponent );
```

Here's a good resource to start : https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes stopping and starting `ng serve` also helps. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

A decorator (such as `@Component`) needs to be attached to something, you can't just use them on their own. In the case of `@Component`, you need to add a class directly below it:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'ponyracer-app',
    template: `<h1>Hye bud!</h1>`
})
class AppComponent { }
```

I'd really encourage you to [read the Angular tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) - it explains all this!